# Oracle: Update a Column based on comparison between 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables - Table A with data from the current system and Table B with legacy data. I was attempting to update a field on the Table A by appending concatenated data from Table B if there was a match.

However, due to the nature of the data, there's no singular ID field and the matching criteria is the name, date of birth and maiden name fields.

I thought the following might work but I run into a "SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended".

```
UPDATE A
SET A.HISTORY  = A.HISTORY ||'Org:=  ' || B.ORG ||' | Group:=  ' || B.GROUP || ' | Campus:= ' || B.CAMPUS || ' | Year:= ' || B.YEAR || ' | Comments:= ' || B.COMMENT
FROM CURRENT_DATA A, LEGACY_DATA B
WHERE A.DOB             = B.BDOB
AND A.FIRST_NAME        = B.FIRST_AA
AND A.MIDDLE_NAME        = B.MID_AB
AND A.LAST_NAME        = B.LAST_AC
AND A.MAIDEN_NAME = B.MAIDEN_AD;
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction re: the above query?

Answer (score 0):

You are basically there. You need to use a sub-query syntax here. Note that there can be two `WHERE` statements here, first within the sub-query, which will define what the sub-query outputs, and another for the `UPDATE` statement itself, which determines which rows get updated. The query below will update all the rows in table `A`. Also, the sub-query should return only one result for each row in `A`.

```
UPDATE A
SET A.HISTORY  = (SELECT
        A.HISTORY ||'Org:=  ' || B.ORG ||' | Group:=  ' || B.GROUP || ' | Campus:= ' || B.CAMPUS || ' | Year:= ' || B.YEAR || ' | Comments:= ' || B.COMMENT
    FROM CURRENT_DATA A, LEGACY_DATA B
    WHERE A.DOB             = B.BDOB
        AND A.FIRST_NAME        = B.FIRST_AA
        AND A.MIDDLE_NAME        = B.MID_AB
        AND A.LAST_NAME        = B.LAST_AC
        AND A.MAIDEN_NAME = B.MAIDEN_AD
    )
--WHERE condition for which rows to updated, if needed
;
```

Comment: Thanks, Munir. I do get multiple results for the Subquery (Select), one for each row in A that matches in B. Am I missing a criteria? As far as the data is concerned, not every record in A will have a match in B.

Comment: What i meant was that each row in A should match one or no rows in B. It should not have multiple rows in B. I think you should be fine. Try testing it on a dummy table and see if it works.